# How to get pasted text in ng-paste?

Tags: angularjs

I tried to get value was inserted in input text:

Angular JS:

```
$scope.pasteYoutube = function (){
    $timeout(function () {
        // get $scope.url from input
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-paste="pasteYoutube()" ng-trim="true" ng-model="url" type="text" class="long-input">
```

But I get `underfined $scope.url`

Comment: See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/halOU64CdQ9kIjsBMnOv?p=preview), to me it works just fine.

Comment: For me does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that angular hasn't processed the input yet. Try adding a timeout value, the default is 0 so the function is executed immediately.

Edit:

change

```
$timeout(function () {
    // get $scope.url from input
});
```

to

```
$timeout(function () {
    // get $scope.url from input
}, 10);
```

This will wait 10 ms to let angular get the url from the input.

Comment: Add more than 0 to timeout?

Comment: BTW why are you using $timeout, do you know that you can also watch for changes in the scope? Take a look at [$watch](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: watch is not firing when i paste